# Loop through data frame to search for multiple patterns and report them

Tags: r, regex, find-occurrences

I am trying to make a loop that counts multiple patterns in rows of a data frame and report the number of occurrences in a new data frame.

Here is my input:

```
input <- data.frame(V1 = LETTERS[1:4], 
             V2 = c("ABCDEF", "AAABBBCCA", "CCAABBCC", "ACCCCCCA"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

List of patterns I want to search for:

```
list<-c("ABC", "AA", "CC", "CCCC", "A")
```

And expected output:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("AAABBBCCA", 
"ABCDEF", "ACCCCCCA", "CCAABBCC"), class = "factor"), ABC = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AA = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), CC = 0:3, CCCC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), A = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 1L), ABC_length = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AA_length = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), CC_length = structure(1:4, .Label = c("0", "1", "1,1", "2"), class = "factor"), CCCC_length = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), A_length = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "1,1", "2", "3,1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2",     "ABC", "AA", "CC", "CCCC", "A", "ABC_length", "AA_length", "CC_length",     "CCCC_length", "A_length"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

One solution could be using str_count or str_locate_all, example below.
But in reality I want to search using the above-mentioned list of patterns.

```
library(stringr)
input$ABC <- str_count(input$ABC, "ABC")
input$ABC_length <- lapply(str_locate_all(input$ABC_length, "ABC"), function(x) {
  paste(x[, 2] - x[, 1] + 1, collapse = ",")
})
```

Comment: just to make it clear, my example includes a solution how to find one pattern "ABC", but the question is about search of multiple patterns

Comment: You don't have a solution to finding the "ABC" pattern because you are referring to a column which you're trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you're referring to the desired output on the right side of your formula.  Instead of

```
input$ABC <- str_count(input$ABC, "ABC")
```

(which doesn't make sense because `input$ABC` hasn't been created yet), try

```
input$ABC = str_count(input$V2, "ABC")
```

Similar logic for `input$ABC_length`:  you need to refer to `input$V2`, not `input$ABC_length`, on the right side of the equation.

Comment: yes, this way I would only get "ABC" counted, can I do it for all combinations in the list?

Comment: The logic is the same:  don't refer to the output column in the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: yes, but how to make a loop which would output the data for each pattern into a data frame